# How to assign a default value to the indexes that are missing from an array in php in numerical indexes?

Tags: php, arrays

I went into a problem where I wanted to assign default values to the array indexes that are missing values.

Example,

I have an array like the below,
`$a = [0=>'hello', 2=>'hi', 5=>'test'];`

Here, indexes 1,3, and 4 are missing. I want to make this array by adding values to the missing indexes the values can be any default value suppose `''` an empty space.

The final array should look like the below,

`$a = [0=>'hello', 1=>'', 2=>'hi',3=>'', 4=>'', 5=>'test'];`

Looking for help to solve this issue.

Comment: Ok, so are you aware about loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php

$array = [0=>'hello', 2=>'hi', 5=>'test'];

$existingKeys = array_keys($array);

//you can use any value instead of Rahul!!!
$newKeys = array_fill_keys(range(min($existingKeys), max($existingKeys)), "Rahul");
$array += $newKeys;

//optional, probably not needed
ksort($array);
print_r($array);
```

?>